# Create shortcode for displaying only subcategories by given parent name Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, categories, shortcode

If would like to have a shortcode that displays a list (dropdown) with ONLY showing subcategories in woocommerce with the given parent ID. 
And if possible without javascript.
 Example shortcode `[display_shortcode parent="6459" ]`

I found this code that displays a dropdown with all categories.
I'm not that good with PHP to edit this code :-(

````
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'show_count'    => '0',
        'hierarchical'  => '0',
        'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    $c = $count;
    $h = $hierarchical;
    $o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby : 'order';

    // Stuck with this until a fix for http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
    woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories( $c, $h, 0, $o );
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var product_cat_dropdown = jQuery(".dropdown_product_cat");
        function onProductCatChange() {
            if ( product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value !=='' ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
        product_cat_dropdown.onchange = onProductCatChange;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

````
function woocommerce_subcats_by_id( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'parent_cat_id' => '',
    ), $atts ) );
 
    $idbyid = get_term_by('id', $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat');
    $product_cat_ID = $idbyid->term_id;
      
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'parent' => $product_cat_ID,
       'hide_empty' => true,
    );
    $subcats = get_categories($args);
    $content = '<ul>';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          $content .= '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
      }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_sub', 'woocommerce_subcats_by_id' );```
````